# What is msstdfmt.dll?

Tags: vb6

The file `msstdfmt.dll` is I believe supplied with Visual Basic 6 and is sometimes a dependency for deployment.

The copy on my PC includes the helpstring

> Microsoft Data Formatting Object Library 6.0 (SP6)

which is not very informative.

What is this DLL for? What are the key functionalities that it provides?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Microsoft documentation:

> The Microsoft Standard Data Formatting Object Library is required for
>   controls that implement a DataFormat property. An Application Error
>   occurs when a control makes an attempt to use the DataFormat property
>   and the Microsoft Standard Data Formatting Object Library is not
>   registered. Controls that implement a DataFormat property include, but
>   are not limited to, the following:
>
> CheckBox, ComboBox, Image, Label, ListBox, PictureBox, TextBox,
>   ImageCombo, MonthView, DTPicker, Calendar, DataCombo, DataList,
>   DBCombo, DBList, MaskEdBox, RichTextBox.

Comment: Wish someone had left a comment about the downvote here. This is useful information.

Comment: Probably as simple as "SO is not a replacement for Google or just opening the manual."

Comment: @Bob77 fortunately when dealing with 20+ year old VB6 software SO is a very useful supplementary documentation. Microsoft links and pages have been withering away and this seems even more accelerated recently.

Comment: So just crack open the MSDN Library CHM Help that comes with every legal copy of VB6.

Answer (score 2):

It is used pretty extensively for data formatting.

It gets used implicitly with many databound controls and when you create databound UserControls or datasource UserControls and Classes.  Instances of the `StdDataFormat` object it provides can also be used explicitly, either for direct use in code or even assigned to an ADO `Field` object's `DataFormat` property.

It is a pretty fundamental library for any VB6 program that is not written in "Let's pretend we are writing QBasic" i.e. Dark World scripting mode.  Egad, you may as well be using stone knives and bearskins (a.k.a. Python).